# Where to get Android Studio Artic Fox uninstall.exe file?

Tags: windows, android-studio

Currently, I've had some issues with android studio plugins not working correctly so I tried to uninstall and reinstall android studio but it failed as the uninstall.exe is missing. I've directly located and uninstalled most of the files for android studio and reinstalled it but the same thing occurred where no uninstall.exe was on the directory. I tried to use the new installer to see if it would give me the option to uninstall the pre-existing version but it didn't work. Also, I tried to download the zip contain the files of android studio instead of the recommended installer but there was no uninstall.exe.