# Where is uninstall.exe located in android studio 4+?

Tags: android, android-studio, uninstallation

**Where is uninstall.exe located in android studio 4+?**

I recently updated my android studio from version 2020.3 to 2021.1.1 and its causing some issues. Tried to go back to 2020.3 but when I try to uninstall it from windows settings panel the following message shows up.

[image: Error]

Went to check inside the file explorer and it really does not have the **uninstall.exe** file.

[image]

I am convinced that there could be an easier solution to this instead of needing to download an older version of Android studio and needing to extract unintall.exe file and copy/paste it in mine.

I have already viewed the following questions

[could not find uninstall.exe android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087412/could-not-find-uninstall-exe-android-studio#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20folder%20where,this%20should%20solve%20the%20problem.)

[Where to get Android Studio Artic Fox uninstall.exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666927/where-to-get-android-studio-artic-fox-uninstall-exe-file)

Comment: In my system there is no uninstall.exe but I also don't have Android Studio in the list of installed applications (but it is installed). Seems that one of the updates have messed up with the uninstaller. Seems like you have to remove Android Studio manually and then install the older version by yourself: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: @Robert i wish there was a sensible solution to this, but okay